# Haskell read n numbers from user and return their sum

Tags: haskell, io, sum

I'm trying to write a function `isums` that reads `n` numbers from user and returns their sum. Also, after each number, the sum up to that number is printed. I have this so far:

```
isums :: Int -> IO Int
isums n = do
    num <- readLn
    putStrLn (show (num + sum))
    sum <- isums (n - 1)
    return (num + sum)
```

Also I'm not using IORef.

Comment: Solution with `replicateM` is preferable, while recursion (as in other answer) is “goto of functional programming”. So I suggest switching “solution” mark to the answer with `replicateM`.

Comment: The `replicateM` solution didn't have the printing of the sum after every number, so it isn't a solution to this particular function.

Comment: Equating explicit recursion with using goto is a bit extreme, but I like the idea. :)

Comment: @Aelin oh, missed that, sorry. Still, the part about printing partial sums is orthogonal to `replicateM`-one. To get those you could replace `sum` from that answer with `scanl (+) 0`.

Comment: @chepner the idea is not my, it's Erik Meijer's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one more solution: it builds on the last version of the @Willem's one, but instead of using a list of `()`'s (which is a bit underwhelming) as a fuel for the loop (`foldM`) it applies a list of actions for reading the values.

```
import Control.Monad

isums n = foldM go 0 (replicate n readLn) 
  where
    go s a = do 
      x <- a
      let s' = s + x 
      print s'
      return s'
```

Here `replicate n readLn` creates a list of actions, each of which reads an integer. These actions are not evaluated till the `go` is called during the looping by means of `foldM`. The fact that we can create such a list without performing actual reading stems from the Haskell's laziness.

Comment: Nice use of the list of lazy IO actions - I'd hoped something like that was possible, but I hadn't got round to testing it.

Answer (score 3):

This would probably be easiest to express using a helper function, as the extra requirement of printing the partial sums after each input adds a bit of extra clutter:

```
isums :: Int -> IO Int
isums n = helper n 0
  where
    helper 0 acc = return acc
    helper m acc = do
        x <- readLn
        let x' = acc + x
        print x'
        helper (m - 1) x'
```

---

What you're doing is kinda like a fold (look at [`foldM`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=foldM&scope=set%3Astackage)), only instead of traversing a list, you're getting the values "to be folded" from IO. If we had a function:

```
accM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> m a -> Int -> m a
accM f acc 0 = acc
accM f acc n = accM f (acc >>= f) (n - 1)
```

Then we could write this as:

```
isums :: Int -> IO Int
isums n = accM helper (return 0) n
  where
    helper acc = do
        x <- readLn
        let x' = acc + x
        print x'
        return x'
```

Which is a bit nicer (and more reusable) as it lets us separate the general behaviour (`accM`) from the specific behaviour (`helper`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`replicateM :: Applicative m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) for this:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

isums :: (Read n, Num n) => Int -> IO n
isums n = do
    numbers <- replicateM n readLn
    return (sum numbers)
```

So here we repeat `readLn` the given number of times, and then we return the `sum` of the `numbers` list.

An equivalent can be achieved with an `fmap`:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

isums :: (Read n, Num n) => Int -> IO n
isums n = fmap sum (replicateM n readLn)
```

Or even *pointfree* (and *pointless*):

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

isums :: (Read n, Num n) => Int -> IO n
isums = fmap sum . flip replicateM readLn
```

We can also produce a list of partial sums with `scanl`:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

isums :: (Read n, Num n) => Int -> IO [n]
isums = fmap (scanl (+) 0) . flip replicateM readLn
```

and then later process the list, or in case we need to print these, and return the last one, we can perform a `mapM` on that list, like:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

isums :: (Read n, Num n) => Int -> IO ()
isums n = fmap (scanl (+) 0) (replicateM n readLn) >>= mapM_ print
```

Or in case we need to print the partial sums:

```
isums :: (Read n, Num n, Show n) => Int -> IO n
isums n = foldM f 0 (replicate n ())
    where f a _ = readLn >>= \b -> let c = a + b in print c >> return c
```

Comment: They say the part about printing partial sums is not addressed in the answer. Perhaps, you could update it, so we might persuade OP to use library functions instead of plain recursion.